# TensorFlowを実行しようとするとエラーが出ます: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

TensorFlowのバージョンを確認しようとしたり、実行しようとしたりすると、以下のようなエラーが出ます。
試行錯誤していますが一向になおりません。何か対策あればご教示願います。

**実行環境**

- Anaconda 1.9.12
- Python 3.8
- Tensorflow <- バージョンは不明。調べようとすると以下のエラーが出ます

**今まで試したこと**　⇒　いずれもダメでした

- uninstallしてinstallしなおした
- condaコマンドでインストールしてみた。

**出力されるエラー**

```
(tensorflow) PS C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito> python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
(tensorflow) PS C:\Users\Atsuhito.Ito>
```

Comment: おそらく Windows のどれかの環境と思うのですが、どのような OS をお使いかなども「実行環境」に書いてくださると嬉しいです。

Comment: AnacondaのWin64だと、まだTensorFloww自身がPython3.8をサポートしていない版数(2.1.0)の可能性があります。[anaconda/packages/tensorflow 2.2.0](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow) Linux系で作業するか、pipでインストールするか、あたりでしょうか。[How to install TensorFlow with Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809495/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-python-3-8) あるいはPython3.6の環境を構築するとか。[自分のMinicondaの環境構築の備忘メモ](https://qiita.com/hatorijobs/items/4db0ce7f90188fa224e2)

Comment: あと、Pythonで実行しなくても、Anaconda NavigatorのGUIでTensorFlowの版数は調べられるのでは？

Comment: 解決しました。ご指摘の通り、Python3.8の環境になっており、TensorFlowが動作しなかったようです。3.6環境にしたら動きました！お手数おかけしました。

Answer (score 1):

コメントで解決とのことなので、一応回答として記述しておきます。

おそらく現時点ではWindowsのAnacondaでインストールできるTensorFlowはPython3.8をサポートしていない2.1.0版と思われます。

以下は現時点でのAnacondaのパッケージ情報
[anaconda/packages/tensorflow 2.2.0](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow)

> Installers
> conda install
> linux-64  v2.2.0
> win-64  v2.1.0
> osx-64  v2.0.0
> To install this package with conda run:
>
> ```
> conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
> ```

Python3.8で動作するTensorFlowは 2.2 以後という記事
[How to install TensorFlow with Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809495/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-python-3-8)

> As of May 7, 2020, according to Tensorflow's Installation page with pip, Python 3.8 is now supported. Python 3.8 support requires TensorFlow 2.2 or later.
> You should be able to install it normally via pip.
>
> ---
>
> Prior to May 2020:
> As you mentioned, it is currently not supported by Python 3.8, but is by Python 3.7.
> You want to have `virtualenv` installed. You also need Python 3.7. Then you can just start a `virtualenv` with `-p python3.7` and install it using pip like you did before:
> 以下省略

---

解決策としては、Linux系で作業するか、pipでインストールするか、あたりが考えられますが、一番簡単なのは、使えるTensorFlowの版数が古くなりますがPython3.6環境を作成してTensorFlowをインストールすることでしょう。

こちらの記事が参考になると思われます。
[自分のMinicondaの環境構築の備忘メモ](https://qiita.com/hatorijobs/items/4db0ce7f90188fa224e2)